# Is finding a clique containing at least half of the vertices in NP-complete?

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

I guess one can answer with yes, but I couldn't come with a reduction.

I tried to reduce from the normal clique-problem with an input $k$.

Is there a clique with a minimum of $k$ vertices?

> Case 1: $k \geq \frac{|V(G))|}{2}$ one can add m vertices with $m := 2k - |V(G)|$
>
> Case 2: $k < \frac{|V(G))|}{2}$ is not clear to me

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.

---

Given a graph $G=(V, E)$ and a number $k$, I'll describe a reduction from $$L:=\{(G,k)|G \text{ contains a clique of size } \geq k\}$$ to the language

$$HC:=\{(G)|G \text{ contains a clique of size } \geq\vert\frac{V(G)}{2}\vert\}$$

---

Build a new graph $H=G\cup K_m$ were $m=\vert V(G)\vert - k$.
Also, add edges by connecting every vertex in $K_m$ with every vertex in $G$

> Prop: $H$ has a clique of size $\geq \vert\frac{V(H)}{2}\vert\iff G$  has a clique of size $\geq k$

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! Do you focus on k < |V(G)|/2 ? I guess it should be m := |V(G)| - 2k then.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what do you mean. For example, if $k=\frac{2\vert V(G)\vert}{3}$ then $m=\frac{\vert V(G)\vert}{3}$. I don't see any problem. I think you are confusing the directions

Comment: In your example $|V(H)| = \frac{4|V(G))|}{3}$ Now suppose H has a clique of size $\geq \frac{2|V(G))|}{3}$ this is aquivalent for a clique in G of size $\geq \frac{2|V(G))|}{3} - m = \frac{|V(G))|}{3}$.... but thats $< k = \frac{2|V(G))|}{3}$

Comment: So in your case is $k = \frac{2|V(G))|}{3}  > \frac{|V(G))|}{2}$ so you just need to add $\frac{|V(G))|}{3}$ new vertices and you're ok. But in case $k < \frac{|V(G))|}{2}$  it's correct to add $K_m$ with $m = |V(G)| - k$ and add edges by connecting every vertex in $K_m$ with every vertex in $G$

Comment: Sorry, still not sure what do you mean. Do you think that there is any mistake in the proof? Or are you saying the reduction can be more efficient?

Comment: Yes there is a mistake in my opinion. In my comment I show it with your example...Same mistake in your proof

Comment: I still don't get what is the problem. For example, assume $k=4$ then, $G$ has a clique of size $\geq 4\implies H$ has a clique of size$\geq \frac{\vert V(H) \vert}{2}$. The other direction is exactly the same. Could you please try to explain what is the problem again?

Comment: Are you saying when $k<\frac{\vert V(G)\vert  }{2}$ then $m$ **can** be equal to $\vert V(G)\vert-2k$ or **MUST** be equal to $\vert V(G)\vert-2k$?

Comment: Ok $k=4$ and $|V(G)|=10$. So in your proof $m = 10-4 = 6$. Now $|V(H)| = |V(G)| + m = 16$. So we are searching for a clique in H with $\geq\frac{|V(G))|}{2} = 8$ vertices. Suppose we found a 8-Clique in H. This 8-clique is NOT equal to a 4-clique in G, because we added a 6-Clique to G and connected all of its vertices to all of G's vertices....The discovered 8-Clique hence is equal to a 2-clique in G... but we wanted a $\geq k = 4$ clique

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103908/discussion-between-theholyjoker-and-fabi).